# Interaction between runtime and fusion sequences

Tags: c++, boost-fusion

Further to my question [C++ Tuple of Boost.Range - get Tuple of element types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010791/c-tuple-of-boost-range-get-tuple-of-element-types)

I have the following:

```
TupleOfRanges ranges; 
TupleOfElements elements;

std::vector<int> offsets;
```

All containers (both meta and runtime) are of size `N`.  I would like to write code that does the following:

```
boost::fusion::at_c<0>(elements) 
    = *(boost::begin(boost::fusion::at_c<0>(ranges)) + offset[0]);
boost::fusion::at_c<1>(elements) 
    = *(boost::begin(boost::fusion::at_c<1>(ranges)) + offset[1]);
// ...
boost::fusion::at_c<N>(elements) 
    = *(boost::begin(boost::fusion::at_c<N>(ranges)) + offset[N]);
```

I have tried writing this using Fusion's `transform` operation but the problem would seem to be that the functor does not know the index of the element it is operating on.

I thought that something like:

```
elements 
    = boost::fusion::transform(boost::fusion::zip(ranges, indices), getValue);
```

might work if I could somehow make Fusion sequence `indices` containing `int 0...N`

So can someone help me make an ascending sequence, or find a better way to achieve my goal?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a sequence of ascending non-type template parameters with [boost::mpl::range_c](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/range-c.html). You will need to copy this sequence to another mpl::sequence as ranges don't fulfil all necessary concept requirements to be used with `transform`. The sequence can be adapted with `fusion`.